# Canvas(and/or labelframe) background, odd gray color

Tags: python

I'm having a hard time figuring out where a grey color is coming from, first a picture to illustrate:

[image: The picture]

As you can see I have drawn 3 arrows which (I know it is a bit hard to see) show the grey outline.

My code goes:

```
master = Tk()
master.title("Skrå kast")
master.resizable(width = FALSE, height = FALSE)
w = Canvas(master, width=630, height=598, bg="#FFFFFF")
w.grid(row = 1, column = 2)

#...

labelframe = LabelFrame(master, text = "Parametre for affyring", background = '#FFFFFF', bd = 3, font = ("Aeria", "8", "bold"))
labelframe.grid(row = 1, column = 1, ipady = 217, ipadx = 2, padx = 3, pady= 2, sticky = N)

#...

w.create_rectangle(10, 4, 630, 596, fill = "#ffffff", outline = "#000000")
w.create_text(320, 30, text = "Simulering af skud med kugle", fill = "#000000", font = ("Arial", "20", "bold"))
```

Where on earth is that grey outline coming from?

I suspect it is the labelframe, however I have not been able to find a way to get rid of it. Not even tampering with the paddings work.

Comment: Somehow when i opened up my project today they grey outline was gone - still have no idea what may have caused it or resolved it though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That color is almost certainly the background color of the root widget. You can check it pretty easily by doing something like `master.configure(background="red")` to see if this mystery color becomes red.

Comment: There we go. The color became red so you we're absolutely correct. Accepted and upvoted - cheers :-)